# Coupled Coils: direction of the magnetic flux

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance, electronics

Reading the description of the *dot convention*, I have found that it makes use of the *direction* of the magnetic flow:

> The *corresponding terminals* are those which, when the current enters through them, produce a magnetic flow of the same direction. They are marked with a dot when represented in a diagram.
>
> [image]

This is something that confuses me since magnetic flow is a scalar, not a vector:

$$\Phi=\int_{S} \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{S}$$

I guess it has to do with how the orientation of the differential area vector is defined, but it is not entirely clear to me. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic flux is indeed a scalar, defined by the equation that you've given. But the scalar can be negative, zero or positive. To make life simple, suppose that $\mathbf B$ is uniform all over S, and that S is a plane piece of surface. S is arbitrarily assigned the direction of one of its two normals. Then if $\mathbf B$ is in the direction of that normal, the dot product is positive, and if it is in the opposite direction the dot product is negative.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not sure how this is used in the definition of the corresponding terminals, because you can choose the surface vector with two different orientations within each coil... Must these two vectors flow through the metal core in the same direction?

Comment: It's simplest to choose the $\vec S$ to be downwards (or upwards) on the left hand side and upwards (or downwards) on the right hand side, so that $\Phi$ is positive if its *sense* is anticlockwise (or clockwise) around the core if $\vec B$ in the core inside either coil is in the direction of $\vec S$ for that part of the core.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic flux is not just a [scaler](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-1/Scalars-and-Vectors#:%7E:text=Scalars%20are%20quantities%20that%20are,a%20magnitude%20and%20a%20direction.), it can be a phasor quantity.  In the case of the AC transformer, it is created by sinusoidal excitation. As such, the flux at any point in the magnetic circuit can be thought of as a sinusoidal phasor (magnitude and phase angle, neglecting nonlinearities that come with saturation and hysteresis).  Just like phasor voltages and  currents in an AC electrical circuit at steady state.

The magnetic flux is directly proportional to the current.

$$\phi =magnetic flux$$
The magnetic flux linkage is,
$$ \lambda = N\phi$$

and in a linear inductor (flux linkage proportional to current through the coil),
$$\lambda = Li$$
where i is the coil current.  So, sinusoidal current means sinusoidal flux.

And, the voltage induced (per Faraday's law of induction),
$$v=\frac{\mathbb d \lambda} {\mathbb d t}=L\frac{\mathbb d i} {\mathbb d t}$$

Comment: I think that user266148 is concerned with the flux at any instant. The phasor representation is only relevant when we describe a sinusoidal variation of flux with time.

Comment: I see.  Then he can rely on Faraday (and Lenz) to see resulting direction of flux created by current in the coil.